# Android Wear: how to share code between the wearable and handheld modules?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I am making an Android app with Wear capabilities.

I want to share some code between the wearable and handheld modules. Specifically, I want to share communication code that uses Google Play Services classes, e.g. `com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient`.

The obvious way to do this is to have a module (I called it `common`) and add a dependency to it in both the handheld and the wearable modules.

Since this common module uses Play Services, I need to make it depend on `com.google.android.gms:play-services`.

I was not sure what to put for the version number - the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) says to use `5.0.77`, but that does not work, as the latest SDK does not have this version anywhere, instead it comes with `5.0.89` and `5.2.08`.

If I use `5.0.89`, the Wearable app does not work, with this error: `Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 5077534`.  The version on the watch is older than the one I used to compile.

Instead of depending on `com.google.android.gms:play-services` the common module could depend on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable` but then there is a conflict when building because the handheld module depends on `com.google.android.gms:play-services`, and these two artefacts use the same package name (`com.google.android.gms`), and so the gradle build fails.

What's the solution?

.

**EDIT** after discussing a bit and to make my question clearer.

To be able to use communication APIs in my `common` module I have two choices:

1. Make `common` depend on `com.google.android.gms:play-services`
2. Make `common` depend on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wear`

⇒ Solution 1 does not work because the version available (5.0.89) for development is more recent than the one on the watch (5.0.77).

⇒ Solution 2 does not work because the `handheld` module already depends on `com.google.android.gms:play-services`, which conflicts with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-wear`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bumped into the same problem a few days ago. My shared module depended on `com.google.android.gms:play-services` as well, so Gradle refused to build and kept nagging at me:

> `Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms`

I added this line to my **mobile** project's gradle file and the error disappeared magically:

> `compile(project(':sharedModule')) {
>        transitive = false 
>   }`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here: https://github.com/tajchert/SWear_Weather

I had created common project that is shared between mobile and wear, and contains my constants. Remember to set there dummy manifest file and:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in build.gradle file.

I had also encountered problem with `play-services` version - I had solved it by using

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'`

instead of specifying particular version - to be honest it should be separete question - as it is out of scope of previous (sharing code between projects).

It is possible to need invalidate cache/restart after changing - you can/should remove build paths in your projects to get rid of all other versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, so it means your common module depends on `play-services-wearable`, and since your mobile module depends on common, it also depends on it (transitively).  Because of that it cannot also depend on `play-services`. Correct?

Comment: No, my common project doesn't depend on 'play-services' because there is no need for it.
Only wear and mobile project does as they use play services to share data.
You can check it on listed above github in build.gradle file in each project.

Comment: Ok then it doesn't really apply to my question, sorry :)  I am trying to share communication code that relies on `play-services` APIs.

Comment: But why you just can't add code in common project (as my constants) and make there a dependency such as `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'`? There is no difference between constants and methods (at least not such that they are treated differently). I just tried and it works.

Comment: Well I tried that, but like I said in the question: there is a conflict when building because the handheld module depends on com.google.android.gms:play-services, and these two artefacts use the same package name (com.google.android.gms), and so the gradle build fails.

Comment: @BoD I'm in the same situation as you, and it looks like having `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'` as a dependency includes `'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'`

Comment: @Eliezer I actually don't have an issue with `com.google.android.support:wearable`.  I am going to add a clarification in the original question right now to make it absolutely clear :)

Comment: Whoops, copy-pasted the wrong line. That should say having 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+' as a dependency includes 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'. So if you as play-services-wearable in commons, and remove play-services from handheld you should be good.